# How to prevent a long process to hangs wxwidgets window

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I have a wxwindows application and in the onclick event of a button, I have a very long process, for example I have something such as this:

```
for(int i=1;i<100;i++)
{
    sleep(1000);
    gaugeProgress->SetValue(i);
      *textOutput<<i;
}
```

Running this code, stops UI to be responsive. I add

```
Refresh();
Update();
```

just after

```
 *textOutput<<i;
```

but it did not work.

is there any way that I can pump the events?

I am working on Windows using VS 20102

Comment: Create a new thread and do the hard-work in that thread. You can send notifications from that thread to the main UI thread if you need to signal progress or completion. Likewise,you can send messages from the main thread to the new thread if you wish to cancel the task. There's lots of tuts around, I'd imagine someone's covered wxWidgets and how to go about this task when using that framework. :)

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks. How to communicate between threads? Is there any help from Boost? I remember that in MFC, there was a method which processed event and it stops wndows from hanging. Is there any such methods in WxWidgets?

Comment: No problem. In the plain win32 world, one would use `SendMessage` or `PostThreadMessage`. I don't use BOOST and haven't needed threads in any of my trivial wx projects. I guess a search for "wxWidgets equivalent to PostThreadMessage" might turn up useful results. This is one of the results, perhaps its helpful: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=8392

Comment: @enhzflep: I found wxYield() which would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In those cases I use wxYield() like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
  // sleep() freezes the program making it unresponsible.
  // sleep(1000);
  gaugeProgress->SetValue(i);
  *textOutput << i;
  // wxYield stops this function execution 
  // to process all the rest of stocked events 
  // including the paint event and resumes immediately.
  wxYield();
}
```

This stops the current process and lets the application to process the message stack like the paint event.

But I think that the proper way to do this should be using threads.

Comment: Such an amazing function!  I did a combination of `wxMilliSleep` with this and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a wxTimer member in your wxwindows, start it in the window constructor, as such:

```
m_timer.Start(1000);
```

then capture the timer event with a function, for example:

```
void mywindow::OnTimer(wxTimerEvent& event)
{
  Refresh();
  Update();
}
```

Make sure you connect the event to the wxTimer member.